# Unable to resolve XXX. Where no service registrations found and number of Rules.FallbackContainers: 0 and number of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers: 0

Tags: c#, dryioc

My app gets error in last line:

```
 var ioc= new DryIoc.Container();
 var Task = DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve<XXX>(ioc);
```

Error received:

> Unable to resolve XXX. Where no service registrations found   and
>   number of Rules.FallbackContainers: 0   and number of
>   Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers: 0

My code:

```
class XXX: AAA
{ ...
}
```

Comment: Just wandering why do you call extension method as static? Why not `ioc.Resolve<XXX>()` instead of `DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve<XXX>(ioc)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to register Class first:

`DryIoc.Registrator.Register(container, typeof(XXX));`